# How to solve error about execution time in google sheets apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that gets text from an image (URL). it worked perfectly when I tried it with 50 rows, but now I need it to work with over 6500 rows and it stops on number 200 aprox. because of excecution time.

is there a way to make the code work for all 7000 rows?

thanks

```
function validar() {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GetTextFromImage");
  var lrow = sh1.getLastRow();
  
  try {
    for(var i = 3;i<=lrow;i++){
    var url = sh1.getRange(i,7).getValue();
    var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title : imageBlob.getName(),
      mimType : imageBlob.getContentType(),

    }
    var options = {
    ocr : true
    }
    
    var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource,imageBlob,options);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
    var text = doc.getBody().getText();
    var newText = text.replace(/ /g, "");
    var finalText = newText.replace (/\n/g,"")
       

    sh1.getRange(i,8).setValue(finalText);
  
   

    Drive.Files.remove(docFile.id);
    }
  } catch(error) {
  return;
}
```

I tried diving the DDBB on less rows, and it worked. buy I expect to do it in online one file.

Comment: You could save some time by getting this ` sh1.getRange(i,7).getValue();` in an array all at one time.  But I suspect that the longest pole in the tent is the fetch.  I'd guess you'll have to do it in batches

Comment: Following to what Cooper said, you can set a column and save same Status in each processed row; when the script runs again it can continue from that point on

Comment: I'd say just store the last processed line in script properties on each itteration and the script would start from that line. I'd suggest what I did before. Have a date object for when you start the script and a date object for when you start a new iteration of your loop and a date object for average loop run time. After each iteration update the average runtime and see if the remaining time until quota is enough for another run. If not create a trigger to run it again after 1 minute and exit out

Comment: @Martín, can you help with the code to run the script again from the last point it ended??

Comment: @MARTINBAHAMONDES I've proposed some ideas in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question in comments, it depends on how your data works; you can set a new column for the status, and say at the end of the loop: `sh1.getRange(i,20).setValue("Finished")` and then in the loop stablish that:

```
if (sh1.getRange(i,20).getValue() == "Finished") {}
else {...the rest of the code...}
```

I'm assuming 20 as the number of column, you can set your own one, obviously

Other thing you could do is have one cell to get the last column you've worked with. Let's say it's cell `Z1` - then, at the end of the loop: `sh1.getRange("Z1").setValue(i)`

And then you start your loop as:

```
for(var i = sh1.getRange("Z1").getValue();i<=lrow;i++) {....
```

Obviously, you can save that `sh1.getRange("Z1").getValue()` in a variable prior to the loop. And at the final end of your code, if the loop finishes you can set again Z1 as 3 in order to start again.

Then, you could set a 10 minute trigger and have it constantly running for as long as you need, getting to all of the rows when the cycle ends